# "Could not load App_Web_*.dll" Exception after ASP.NET compile & recycle

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis

I recently came across code of the following structure:

- `FooService.cs`
- `FooService.svc`
- `Default.aspx`

Content of the files:

**`[FooService.cs]`**

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace FooService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class FooService
    {
        static FooEngine engine = new FooEngine();

        [OperationContract]
        public string Foo()
        {
            return "bar";
        }
    }

    public class FooEngine
    {

    }
}
```

**`[FooService.svc]`**

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Service="FooService.FooService" %>
```

**`[Default.aspx]`**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<% var foo = "bar"; %>
```

We're using .Net 4.0 (Debug) and IIS6 on Windows Server 2003 with a 'fooservice' web and a hostfile entry to call the web service via http://fooservice/FooService.svc and `default.aspx` via http://fooservice/. Everything works perfectly at this point.

However, after the following steps,

1. Change code in default.aspx, save file
2. Load http://fooservice/ (triggers ASP.NET compile)
3. Recycle app pool

a call to http://fooservice/FooService.svc fails and throws the following exception

```
[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_ynlv0b1k, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +39
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +144
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) +208
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +1440
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String normalizedVirtualPath) +44
   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath) +615

[ServiceActivationException: The service '/FooService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_ynlv0b1k, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified..]
   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +679246
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +190
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication context, String routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean flowContext, Boolean ensureWFService) +234
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +355
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

**What exactly is going on here?**

Remarks

- I understand that ASP.NET is compiling and loading a new `App_Web_*.dll` (during step 2), but why is it trying to load the old (deleted) `App_Web_*.dll` after the recycle (3.)?
- using the exact same code inline in `FooService.svc` instead of a separate `FooService.cs` does not have this problem (?)
- removing the static reference to the `FooEngine` also makes this problem go away (?)

Comment: Maybe the problem is related to FooEngine? Will error reproduce if you change FooEngine to object in your example?

Comment: Yes, `FooEngine` is the problem here. But I would like to know *why* it is the problem.

Comment: Did you ever solved it? I facing the same issue

Comment: @ShayErlichmen Not really, we just added aspcompile to our build process.

Answer (score 19):

I just had the same problem,
The app was a web application, so fully precompiled.
This fixed it for me, but I'm not sure why:

```
<compilation debug="false" batch="false">
```

I got this solution from here: http://web.archive.org/web/20140116171941/http://www.creative-jar.com/insights/labs/programming/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-app_web_/

Answer (score 3):

It must be a compiler issue, as it was mentioned before. If you don't have access to the iis, you can modify your own web.config file to use a different temp directory. This modification will make the iis to recompile your code and use this new compilation.

```
<compilation tempDirectory="C:\...">
```

The iis_iusrs user must have write access to this new directory.

Answer (score 2):

The code should not be the following structure:

- FooService.cs
- FooService.svc
- Default.aspx

But the following:

- **App_Code**/FooService.cs
- FooService.svc
- Default.aspx

Notice the special `App_Code` folder which contains the source code.

So to recap:

`~/App_Code/FooService.cs`:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace FooService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public class FooService
    {
        static FooEngine engine = new FooEngine();

        [OperationContract]
        public string Foo()
        {
            return "bar";
        }
    }

    public class FooEngine
    {

    }
}
```

`~/FooService.svc`:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="FooService.FooService" CodeBehind="~/App_Code/FooService.cs" %>
```

`~/Web.config`:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

`~/Default.aspx`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<% var foo = "bar"; %>
```

This being said I would recommend you using [Web Applications instead of Web Sites](http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2008/06/ASPNET-Web-Site-versus-Web-Application-Project.aspx) and precompile everything to avoid those kind of problems. Another advantage is that you no longer need to deploy the source code on the server.

If you use a percompiled web application your structure will be the following:

- bin/MyWebService.dll
- FooService.svc
- Default.aspx

This is what I would recommend you.

Comment: I am well aware of the different ASP.NET setups and deployments and obviously use them in other projects. However, I came across this particular arrangement and asked this question to find out why it behaves the way it does.

Comment: If you are using a web site all source code should be located at the `App_Code` folder. Is this your case?

Comment: It is not, but moving `FooService.cs` to the `App_Code` folder does not change anything in this case - same result.

Answer (score 0):

We've seen that under certain conditions an application recycle never actually executes.  I've seen this on larger sites that are under heavy load.  IIS uses a pretty aggressive caching mechanism and, depending on the request queue length will not actually force a complete recycle.

If you are seeing this then try executing an `IISRESET /noforce`.  This should tell the server to really really recycle everything.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, what I described actually happens *every time*, not just under heavy load. I tried `IISRESET /noforce`: it results in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can set IIS Application pool to recycle at certain time period or certain application failure. Please check following URLs which  might help you:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1551597/3934757.aspx
http://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/archive/2010/07/01/installing-asp-net-4-in-iis-6.aspx

Gaurav Maniar MCP | MCSE | MCST | MCITP | ITILv3 Certified

Comment: That would actually make it worse as the service would become unavailable immediately after the first reset.

Comment: @josef, have you checked URLs and recycle app pool won't affect unavailability of Application pool.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with Asp.Net compiler. It doesn't seem to update temporary ASP.NET files for WCF with new DLL build on recompilation. Could you please test application with batch=false i.e. <compilation batch="false">

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with my project, the website was working fine, but any svc webservices came up with the same error.

I tried changing the line below in web.config, but this didn't help

```
    <compilation debug="false" batch="false">
```

The solution I found was related to how the application was built.

As I was using a deployment project, I found that unchecking the option:

> Treat as library component (remove the App_Code.compiled file)

in the 'Output Assemblies' page, and then rebuilding and deploying the project seemed to work for me.

Hope that helps someone else.